# CKEditor not destroying unless explicitly setting the id

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to destroy an instance of a CKEditor textbox which I'm using for rich text input by using a function so I can pass an ID to it which I can't get to work.

If I use this it works:

```
function destroyCKEditor() {
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['updateNewsText']) CKEDITOR.instances['updateNewsText'].destroy();
}
```

If I use this, it doesn't:

```
var instanceName = 'updateNewsText';

function destroyCKEditor(instanceName) {  
    if (CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName) CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.destroy();
}
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction please... Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your function. To access object's property using a name stored in a variable in JavaScript you need to use `[]` notation instead of a dot notation.

This will work:

```
var instanceName = 'updateNewsText';

function destroyCKEditor(instanceName) {  
    if (CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName]) CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].destroy();
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you very much! I didn't know about using the [] notation.